# Run WinSCP script which is located in different folder than the winscp.com

Tags: batch-file, command-line, winscp

Looking at example on WinSCP forums, I am able to put together a .bat file and associated .txt file, which works ONLY if both files are located under the same location as where WinSCP.com (and other WinSCP related files) is located:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP

Is there a way to run my .bat file successfully without having it under:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP

My .bat file content:

```
winscp.com /script=recon_SFTP.txt
pause
```

I did try moving my .bat file and .txt file to another location and adding location path, but it didn't work.  I am guessing I need to escape spaces from my file path to location winscp.com?:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com /C:\Users\sqlservice\Desktop\SSmith1\script=recon_SFTP.txt
    pause
```

Comment: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script="C:\Users\sqlservice\Desktop\SSmith1\recon_SFTP.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a full path to the script file after the `/script=` switch.

And of course, you have to quote paths that contain spaces, like the path to the `Program Files (x86)`.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script="C:\Users\sqlservice\Desktop\SSmith1\recon_SFTP.txt"
```

Though if the .txt is in the same directory as the .bat and you execute the .bat from its folder, you do not have to use a full path to the script:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script=recon_SFTP.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose any string conaining spaces that you want to be treated as a single string in "double quotes"

Answer (score 1):

You could also add the WinSCP installation directory to your PATH.  Then you can call winscp.com from any directory.

[Add directory to path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)